# Webview recordar el usuario y contraseña

Tags: android-studio, webview, passport

¡Hola!

¿Cómo se puede hacer para que webview cada vez que entremos a una pagina que nos registremos por primera vez, nos guarde el usuario y contraseña para que la próxima vez que entremos a la página web, nos muestre el usuario y contraseña?

Este es el código que tengo

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.todos_webview_1, container, false );

    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById( R.id.webView_Todos);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.acceptCookie();

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);


    mWebView.loadUrl("https://paguinawe.com");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            mWebView.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/error.htm" );
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

P.D. he visto otros post con un título parecido pero no es lo mismo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para este objetivo se creo el método [getSavePassword()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getSavePassword()), el cual estas usando:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
```

pero desde la API 18 (4.3.x), este método fue marcado como obsoleto, la razón es debida a cuestiones de seguridad de la información la cual podría ser comprometida.

Te sugiero hacer uso de un Web Service y realizar peticiones mediante [OAuth](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) , de otra forma si deseas guardar la información en disco esto no sería seguro pero en este caso puedes hacer uso de un método de almacenamiento como archivo de texto, base de datos o preferencias.

Ejemplo usando sharedPreferences:

Guardar contraseña

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MIS_PREFERENCIAS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("PASSWORD", valor_password);
editor.commit();
```

Obtener contraseña

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MIS_PREFERENCIAS", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String password = prefs.getString("PASSWORD", null);
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, estoy intentado utilizar ese código, pero no sé cómo, podrías ponerlo junto con el código de arriba para ver como hay que utilizarlo, aunque no se muy bien si es lo que estoy buscando, si guardo el usuario por ejemplo con el método SharedPreferences, luego cuando abra una página web donde tenga que poner el usuario, como aparece esos datos dentro de la página web para no tener que rellenar esos campos, hay que tener en cuenta que una pagina puede tener una contraseña y otra pagina tener otra contraseña.

Comment: Por cierto, ya que no me deja editar el comentario anterior, lo estoy utilizando en una clase de extiende de un Fragment.